# Glibc errors in Alpine Linux tried everything

Tags: linux, gnu, glibc, alpine-linux

I'am trying to set up a Roon Bridge which is a server streaming endpoint I'am walking against some problems though.. I tried everything but it does not seem to get working. First are some tests, and then you can start the server.

I have got all the necessary packages installed. The board is armv7l

First of all I tried gcompat this give me nothing else then segmentation errors.

Then I tried libc6-compat which first went good.

```
> Checking to see if RoonBridge can run on this machine
>     
>         Checking for Binary Compatibility                            [ SUCCES ]
>         Checking for ALSA Libraries                                  [ SUCCES ]
>     
> STATUS: SUCCES
```

Then, when i tried to start it:

```
> Error relocating /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen:
> pthread_getname_np: symbol not found Error relocating
> /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: __isinf: symbol not found
> Error relocating /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen:
> backtrace_symbols: symbol not found Error relocating
> /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: __isnanf: symbol not found
> Error relocating /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: backtrace:
> symbol not found Error relocating
> /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: __isnan: symbol not found
> Error relocating /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: __finite:
> symbol not found Error relocating
> /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: __isinff: symbol not found
> Error relocating /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen:
> __pthread_register_cancel: symbol not found Error relocating /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: __pthread_unregister_cancel:
> symbol not found Error relocating
> /roon/RoonBridge/RoonMono/bin/mono-sgen: getprotobyname_r: symbol not
> found
```

I know these are glibc errors but cannot find any solutions on the web for them.

Then I tried glibc.apk from https://github.com/gokalper/glibc-alpine-arm32v7 was the only armv7 i could find.

The binaries passed the test, ALSA failed. So i did the ALSA check manual with check_alsa which is  provided in the package result:

> libasound2.0.0 segmentation fault needed by check_alsa
> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 111: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!

Weird thing is I can start the server with glibc.apk .. Its not showing up in Roon core probably because it does not recognize ALSA.

Anyone got any ideas? thanks in advance